# Timeout issues with ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

We're trying to diagnose a performance problem in our web application, and we feel that we've narrowed down to errors that we are seeing in the server's event log.

```
Exception:  System.Web.HttpException
Message:  Request timed out.
Location: /Services/AjaxService.svc/ReleaseCurrentClient
```

That's the entirety of the message.  This is manifesting in pages that hang and take an inordinately long time to load.  The error is sporadic and we cannot reproduce it on demand, but it is an ongoing issue.  Has anyone encountered problems like this with the AjaxControlToolkit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could use a tool like Fiddler and check what's going on with the AJAX calls?

Comment: You can increase the `AsyncPostBackTimeout` of the ScriptManager/ToolkitScriptmanager. I assume that something on the server takes too much time, maybe a database query.

Comment: AsyncPostBackTimeout setled by 600. is it seconds or miliseconds? I found source... AsyncPostBackTimeout = 600 seconds